# mongoose: update element in json array

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to update a user document that looks like this:

```
{
_id:"xyzdon'tcare",
username:"john",
examTrials:Array[
    {
        trialId:"x1",
        examId:"y",
        questions:Array[
            {ques1 Object},
            {ques2 object}
        ]
    },
    {
        trialId:"x2",
        examId:"z",
        questions:Array[
            {ques1 Object},
            {ques2 object}
        ]
    }]
}
```

I tried the most straightforward way, findOne() then modify the document then save().The problem is, I faced race condition problems with the document versions when a new request arrived before the previous update finished.

Now I'm tring to use findOneAndUpdate() to update a question object inside the questions array in a specific trial and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The information I have:

- trial Id
- question obj
- question Id

I think this is all i need. Any help?

------------ EDIT

```
app.post('/updatetrialsession',authenticateJWT ,(req,res)=>{
        User.findOneAndUpdate({
        username: req.user.username
      }, {
           $set: {'examTrials.$[elem1].questions.$[elem2]' : req.body.question,
                'examTrials.$[elem1].currentQuestion':req.body.questionIdx+1 }
      }, {
           arrayFilters: [{'elem1.trialId': req.body.trialId }, {'elem2': req.body.questionIdx}]
      }).then(res=>{
          console.log("updated")
      })
})
```

currentQuestion updated, but the question object didn't.

Comment: for the time being, I managed to update the whole array by making a copy of it, modifying it then using 
var filter={
                    'username':user.username
                }
                var update={
                    $set:{
                        'examTrials':user.examTrials
                    }
                }
                User.findOneAndUpdate(filter,update,{new:true}).then(user=>{
                    console.log('updated')
                })
But this is inefficient, I need a way to update the specific record in the array.. still can't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mongoose `arrayFilter` to update your a field in an array.

For example if you have `userId` to query your user, `trialId` to query your exam trial, `questionId` to query your question, and `newQuestionObject` as your update to the question this code will do the work for you:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: userId
}, {
     $set: {'examTrials.$[elem1].questions.$[elem2]' : newQuestionObject}
}, {
     arrayFilters: [{'elem1.trialId': trialId}, {'elem2': questionId}]
});
```

Or if you want to update specific field of question object you can simply do that like this:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: userId
}, {
     $set: {'examTrials.$[elem1].questions.$[elem2].status' : 'newStatus'}
}, {
     arrayFilters: [{'elem1.trialId': trialId}, {'elem2': questionId}]
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful Thank you! 
however, when i use this method to update say examId, it works.
but the question obj(which I actually need to change) doesn't.
should I mark the array modified as I do with the save function?

Comment: Please try 'elem2._id'  in `arrayFilters` or whatever field you set for your question id in schema.

Comment: I didn't think I'd need a schema for the questions. I simply set the type for the array in the schema to MIxed. I guess there is no way around it and I can't just update it with only the index. I'll change it and post an update.

Comment: It Worked!
THANK YOU SO MUCH. I spent so much time on this.

Comment: Hey another thing please if you don't mind.
Whenever I call this multiple times on the same document,, some of the updates are discarded. Do you have any idea how can I avoid this?

Comment: I believe it's because findOneAndUpdate overrides the document. and some requests arrive before the other requests finish. But I can't think of a way to solve this.